# How to exit emergency mode and boot to default mode?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

When I started my laptop I found this message:

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in,type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D
to try again to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintainence
(or type control-D to continue):
```

I have tried all the above commands but nothing happens.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem)

Comment: Not a dupe. Please stop voting all the emergency mode questions as dupe of that post. This symptom could have many causes

Answer (score 29):

When you see Ctrl+D enter root password.
Then run `mount -a` to see where the error is (which line).

Then enter `sudoedit /etc/fstab` and correct the missing or remove it, then save and finally reboot with `sudo reboot`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't enter any of those commands until you "Give root password for maintenance".

You have the two choices it gives, plus some others.

1. Give the root password. This may be your password. I'm stuck at this myself with my Kubuntu computer.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and it'll try again (and probably fail again).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which will usually reboot the computer. With many computers pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> during the boot process may give you more details and options.
4. Hold down a power button, or physically disconnect power (remove battery).

If you can't remember the root password, [the Ubuntu wiki help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) or [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) may help.

Comment: I had my bootable sdcard corrupted so ìt didn't boot to OS from the first time. CTRL+ALT+DEL helped me to reboot device and the next boot was successful.

Answer (score 5):

Thankfully I had a hunch why my computer (Debian Jessie) couldn't boot (I had changed fstab wrongly), but of course couldn't get in because I had OP's problem.

[skierpage's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/752047/343512) had my solution, which was on the [ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword). Specifically, the steps I took was "The Other Way":

1. At the boot menu, type `e` to edit the boot command.
2. Change `ro` to `rw init=/bin/bash`

Then `F10` to boot and I was able to access a passwordless root shell and could edit `/etc/fstab` to undo my changes.

Answer (score 5):

```
 #mount -a
```

it will mount all disks and shows all unmounted mount points.

then go to

```
    # vi /etc/fstab
```

comment that unmounted mount points in fstab

then

```
   #reboot
```