# Power Outtage - Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, 15.10

Can Kubuntu 15.10 normally recover from a mains power failure?

Computer will not boot normally - always goes to Emergency Mode.

In the emergency mode i tried the options there - no result.

Solved.

- In the end, it was very simple! The monitor is very bad, so the text cmds. on the emergency screen was not what i saw.

I was able after this to get the log, and delete the file stopping the normal boot.

Comment: Kubuntu now will not boot normally. It only goes to Emergency Mode

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/685946/475183 Similiar problem

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem Would this work for my case also?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information, don't just put it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it depends what you mean by recover.

The ability of a computer to recover on any operating system depends on the following things:

- Resilient hardware. Power failures are indicative of poor power networks. These can otherwise fry cheap and bad components. If you get a power spike post-cut (as is very common) your computers might suffer hardware failure.
- Is BIOS set to turn back on after a power cut?
- Disk integrity. Are your partitions using journalled write buffers? Are RAID cards using battery backed write buffers?
- Are you applications saving stuff automatically?

So we can look at software and I'd certainly make sure things you use a lot are doing autosaves, but if you're in a situation where failure is likely, I'd seriously recommend sticking a battery between the computer and the grid.

You can configure Ubuntu to suspend on power failure. For most desktops this means you can get *many hours* of suspend. That's usually enough to get you through all but the worst power cuts and if that looks likely, you might have enough power to resume and save what you need.

Comment: To be more clear so - Im using a Desktop computer, its very resilient. I have never had any problems with it. Power failures are very rare here. - Bios is running fine, I can boot to Restor Mode in Ubuntu - I ran fsck and all disks came back ok, I have one disk. I have a backup program running normally, backintime, for importatnt documents etc. -

Comment: How can I boot Kubuntu normally - ie. get out of emergency mode?

Comment: What do you mean by emergency mode?

Comment: What I mean by recover is...go back to normal...without the emergency mode.. :)

Comment: "Emergency mode" screen appears after I restart the computer. There are several options listed here. I have tried them all and they don't appear to do anything.