# How to exit emergency mode Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and everything was working fine until I rebooted and got stuck with this emergency mode message.

[image]

```
/dev/sda6: recovering journal
/dev/sda6: clean, 193225/9527296 files, 1610280/38077184 blocks
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view 
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance   
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Even if I press Ctrl+D nothing works. I cannot log in. I have already tried using `nomodeset` but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest that you also try `systemctl default` as suggested by the CLI. If this does not help, there is a similar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem/).

Comment: That worked for me but how about how to diagnose what caused Ubuntu to boot into emergency mode?