# Unable to boot (or reinstall) Kubuntu 16.04 after upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi, squashfs

After doing some updates/upgrades (unfortunately I don't remember names of the packages) I am not able to boot into Kubuntu. It freezes on the "Breathing kubuntu logo".

When I hit escape, I can see following errors (I had to type them here manually, so it is possible, that I might make some typos):

```
[9.436029] [drm.intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [1915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun
[9.436050] [drm.intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [1915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

umount: Can't umount /cdrom: Device or resource busy
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
(...) these two lines repeat quite a few times

[55.219834] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [aa3e07]
[55.220432] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block aa3e07, size[7096]
(...) these two lines repeat quite a few times (just with different ...timecodes? in the square brackets at the beginning)

Bus error

[79.692133] SQUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[79.692701] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0xaa3e07
[55.219834] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [aa3e07]
[55.220432] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block aa3e07, size[7096]

[79.753474] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempt to kill init! exitcode 0x00000007
[79.753474]
[79.754639] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu
[79.755230] Hardware name: LENOVO Lenovo G580/Product Name, BIOS SECN33WW (V2.03) 06/06/2012
[79.755836] 0000000000000086 00000000e62afd6d ffff88013a3f7c50 ffffffff813f1143
[79.756416] ffffffff81cb2b50 ffff88013a3f7ce8 ffff88013a3f7cd8 ffffffff8118bde7
[79.757006] ffff880000000010 ffff88013a3f7ce8 ffff88013a3f7c80 00000000e62afd6d
[79.757605] Call Trace:

(here I got lazy to hand-copy all timestamps and hexa information, I can provide it, if needed, information, that I skipped, is marked in {curly brackets})
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] panic+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] ? perf_event_exit_task+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] do_exit+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] do_group_exit+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] get_signal+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] do_signal+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] ? force sig_info_fault+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] ? __probe_kernel_read+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] ? mm_fault_error+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] prepare_exit_to_usermode+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}
[{timestamp}]  [<{16 hexa digits}>] retint_user+0x{hexa}/0x{hexa}

[79.765834] Kernel Offset: disabled
[79.766446] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempt to kill init! exitcode=0x00000007
[79.766446]
```

After that, I tried to do a fresh installment of Kubuntu 16.04 from USB.

In the boot manager from USB I've chosen to "Install Kubuntu".

It went as follows:

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 448332/1509600 files, 3769787/6054443 blocks
~.mount
ureadahead.service
{list of many .services}
systemd-rfkill.service
dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d1\x2dpart7.swap
dev-disk-by\x2did-wwn\x2d0x50004cf20a67e83f\x2dpart7.swap
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dST1000LM024_HN\x2dm101MBB_S2SMJ9CD547736\x2dpart7.swap
dev-sda7.swap
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-df2bfbbd\x2de7ca\x2d4e37\x2d9b35\x2de51a38e0ab13.swap
systemd-fsckd.service
fsckd-cancel-msg:Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress
fsckd:1:0,0:Checking in progress on 1 disk (0,0% complete)
(... more similar fsckd output)
fsckd:1:14,3:Checking in progress on 1 disk (14,3% complete)
```

At this moment it freezes for a while, than it resumes to boot up (the "typical loading output" with `[  OK  ]` at the beginning of the line.

```
(...)
[  OK  ] Started Run snappy firstboot setup.
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

After pressing Ctrl+D it repeated this exact message.

I have found some strategies, that have worked for other users, like typing "acpi=off" in the boot manager or disabling UEFI, but nothing helps. I also tried to repair my boot using the Boot Repair bootable USB. The "repair" happened without errors, but nothing has changed. Starting Kubuntu in recovery mode doesn't work either.

I thought, that maybe my HDD was broken, but dual booting into Windows 10 (installed on the same physical drive (just on another partition)) works just fine.

(I'm sorry for my english.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tried to install Kubuntu 16.10 from Live USB and it worked for me almost perfectly. I formatted my root partition and kept my /home partition, so I had to reinstall all my programs (without formating the / partition the installation didn't work).

After installing 16.10 I had to solve this issue:
["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem).
The solution provided by *kyodake* worked for me just fine.

Now I'm curious, if it would work before upgrading to 16.10...