# Ubuntu won't boot after a file system check

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

I've got a dual-boot of Ubuntu and Windows and due to some file system inconsistency Ubuntu won't load. It always runs a file system check and then switches to emergency mode. This is a list of errors from the journal:

```
-- Logs begin at Čt 2016-10-20 16:27:28 CEST, end at Čt 2016-10-20 16:29:24 CEST. --
kernel: Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
systemd-fsck[506]: fsck failed with error code 4.
systemd[1]: Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/115d2332-e953-48a1-a0c8-05fef157d207.
```

Trying to fix the Error Parsing PCC Subspaces I've disabled hiberboot in Windows but it didn't help.

I've also tried the most voted suggestion in this thread with no success: ["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem/)

Fsck said:

```
/dev/sda1 clean
```

Fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x38034de7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 453787647 453785600 216.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       968970238 976771071   7800834   3.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3  *    453787648 556187647 102400000  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       556187648 968968191 412780544 196.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       968970240 976771071   7800832   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Would you know about any solution to this?

*EDIT:*

After fsck on sda4, it seems to work fine.

blkid output:

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="e8f7fdb0-1024-496b-aaba-376aeb30849b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="38034de7-05"
/dev/sda1: UUID="9fa78f27-9b26-4f92-bd20-180ed6903220" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="38034de7-01"
/dev/sda3: UUID="249E367E9E364916" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="38034de7-03"
/dev/sda4: UUID="115d2332-e953-48a1-a0c8-05fef157d207" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="38034de7-04"
```

Comment: I had this same exact error. I had to reinstall the OS from a USB stick, then I changed my partition 2 to ext4, and it worked for me.

Comment: Why 2 Linux partitions? root and /home? You need to fsck sda1 AND sda4. Add the output of **sudo blkid** or **cat /etc/fstab** to your question. Let me know how it goes. Cheers, Al

Comment: Al, thanks a lot for your advice. I didn't realize sda4 should be also checked. It's an extra partition for specific files shared with Windows but I think I will have to think about other ways because this seems to cause errors.. I've updated my post with blkid output.

Comment: @DavidFoerster OP says they tried that.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Yes, but according to the comments it turned out that OP misinterpreted the answer(s) to that question originally by running `fsck` on the wrong partition. Once he picked the right partition all went according to plan.