# After ubuntu upgrade to 16.04 - Stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade

I have dual boot system with Windows 10 & Ubuntu.
Recently updated my Ubuntu to version 16.04 LTS.
Ever since when i boot it it gets stuck in emergency mode,
telling me to hit Ctrl+D to try again or login as root.

Ctrl+D Gets me to the same mode again after few minutes.

After some google research, i've disabled hibernation entirely in windows 10
(Which makes fast startup option also disabled)

And still no luck.
Tried shutting windows 10 with `shutdown /s /t 5` - didn't help also.

What can i do?
beside reinstalling earlier Ubuntu version.

BTW, Windows 10 was installed in legacy mode and not UEFI

Thanks

Comment: And this is why, *IMHO*,  you should always clean-install and not upgrade :)

Comment: Maybe so. but i understand this is a common issue when dual-booting windows 10 & ubuntu 16.04, regardless of how the latter was installed.
(Didn't found any common answer, though :|  )

Comment: Nah, Windows 10 isn't what caused the upgrade to fail, especially since it was installed in Legacy mode...

Comment: Ok, maybe you have some useful advice though? :\

Comment: If you enter emergency mode, what is the result of `journalctl -xb`?

Comment: You can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem

Comment: a VERY VERY long output. not sure how to read it or what to search for over there

Comment: Android Dev - No sdb in my case. only sda

Comment: @Adiel - Then use the correct block for your partition