# Ubuntu 16.10 boots into Emergency Mode

Tags: mode

Whenever I turn on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.10, it always boots into Emergency Mode. The only way to get Ubuntu to start successfully is to boot into recovery mode, use dpkg to repair broken packages, and then to resume the normal boot sequence. Pushing CTRL + D just makes the Ubuntu splash screen flash, and then it goes back into Emergency Mode.

Here is the output of journalctl -xb: http://pastebin.com/CLJhR4Vf

[image: Emergency Mode Prompt]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and see if it works

- Make a bootable USB/DVD and Boot into it.
- After the load, open a terminal
- type the commands

  ```
  sudo -i
  fdisk -l
  ```

  *Fdisk will inform you as your partition / (root) called, say for example it is /dev/sdb1, continuous running:*

  ```
  umount /dev/sdb1
  fsck -y /dev/sdb1
  reboot
  ```
- Remove the DVD/USB and boot from the HDD/SDD (whichever is yours)

Comment: should it be not `e2fsck` instead

Comment: @AbelTom fsck is just the original class. e2fsck is like extension of it .used for ext filesystem. Can try that too ;)