# "Welcome to emergency mode!" device descriptor read/64, error -32

Tags: boot, ubuntu-gnome, fsck

I tried booting into Ubuntu (I have dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu) and faced with the following error message:

```
usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
/dev/sda5: contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda5: 433585/1319328 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 3069030/5290240 blocks fsck exited with status code 1
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging it type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. 
Press enter for maintenance
(Or press Control-D to continue)
root@localhost:~#
```

What I've tried:

- I've tried to follow the instructions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/646431/646743) but couldn't resolve the issue (note: I replaced `/dev/sdb1` with `/dev/sda5`) and I get the following message after executing the command `fsck -y /dev/sda5` but after reboot I still had the same error:

> fsck from utill-linux 2.27.1
>
> e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
>
> /dev/sda5: clean, 433587/1319328 files, 3069032/5290240 blocks

- I've tried rebooting and `Ctrl-D`, but nothing was resolved

Any help would be very much appreciated; I really hope I can fix this issue soon because I really need to use my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cause of error is not completely clear. Some believe that "most probably it’s a result of hardware failure rather than a driver or kernel bug." And [this article](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) suggested that "unplugging all USB devices from PC, turnning power off, and waiting a minute or two would do the trick." However,. I didn't have any USB devices plugged into my laptop, so this solution was not helpful, even though it apparently has solved the issue for many other people.

What actually **solved** the issue for me was executing the following command as a root user:

```
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda1
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda2
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda3
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda4
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda5
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda6
root@localhost~# fsck -y /dev/sda7
```