# Can't get past Emergency Mode after Update

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, updates, fsck

This all started with an update.

I saw that there were several updates available. I clicked Install, it grayed out, then returned to ready. So I clicked Install again. Not sure if it had loaded or needed rebooted, I decided to do so. I turned the machine off using the Power button (NOT the in-OS shutdown).

When my computer powered on, I was given the GRUB> line. After much researching (this is my first crash) I gave the command to go into NORMAL Mode. The system scan stops at around 70% when I attempt to boot from there.

A recurring red line in the system log is FSCK ERROR CODE 4

BIOS boot order lists Ubuntu - so it does see it in there - I have put it at first priority. A friend gave me Puppy Linux on a stick, but it isn't recognized. I don't have an OS disc or stick today. I will tomorrow.

I am sitting at Welcome to Emergency Mode! now, but can access BIOS, GRUB> (and from there NORMAL mode), and Emergency! mode.

Can you advise how to get out of here and into normal operations?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Intel i5. MSI Motherboard. Running a two-month old install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with no other OS installed. No intentional hot-rodding or customization.

Comment: Select `rescue mode` from GRUB menu and select `fsck`  to run a _file system check_ and repair any error as seen in the `error message`

Comment: Please check this link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem

Comment: In Normal Mode I selected the most recent recovery mode (from a long list of options) and ran the fsck check. I then ran a damage fix and it gave me a DEV DM-3 error. After some prompts I appear to be back into my regular OS in a limited-access mode (the graphics driver wasn't able to come online in the boot). I've been able to download all my important files and am going to try again with the disc in hand.