# Help! Can't get past 'Welcome to emergency mode!'

Tags: startup, error-handling

This is actually my first time trying out Linux. And I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a used PC I just bought, HP Compaq 8300 Elite SFF with two hard drives. After buying it, the first thing I did is performe a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate on my first hard drive. Thereafter I created two partitions on my second hard drive. One for installing Ubuntu and the other for storage purposes.

While installing Ubuntu I created partitions for root, home and swap. Then I mistakenly chose my second hard drive to boot from resulting in starting Windows everytime I turn on my PC without showing the boot menu. With the comments and answers from CelticWarrior, Zanna, hunch and duncan Ubuntu is now booted from the first hard drive so that the boot menu shows when I turn on my PC giving me the option to choose between various ways of running Ubuntu and starting Windows.

I already tested starting Windows and everything seems to work fine. However, when I want to start Ubuntu, I can't get past a message showing:

'Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): _ '

That's all I see and no matter what I try I can't seem to continue.

I'm a total newbie concerning Linux and I still need to start my first session with Ubuntu. And I hope I can get some help on this great website.

Thank you in advance!

Sincerely,

Mudhnib

Comment: Is this at all related to your question? It's the same problem, although your circumstances seem somewhat unique https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem

Comment: Hi brndn2k! Thank you for your fast comment. The question looks the same, at least the message he is seeing is. But I don't know what fsck is. Also because Ubuntu is in a second hard drive, I'm not sure if the commands are correct for my situation or how to edit those commands if they aren't correct.

Comment: The main issue with dual boot appears to be that Ubuntu has trouble whenever​ Windows has fast boot enabled, because it can't read certain partitions properly. Disabling fast boot may fix it as it did for this fellow https://askubuntu.com/a/868958/647604 removing the mount points altogether may work as well, allowing you to keep fast boot on while also allowing Ubuntu to work https://askubuntu.com/a/768381/647604 Good luck!

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't seem to have an option for fast boot. So that shouldn't be causing this. In the other questions I see /etc/fstab mentioned a lot. So I'll look into that some more. Maybe I can find some sort of guide. For now I tried umount /dev/sdb5 (because that's where my root is and I think that's what I need from the suggestions) and fsck -y /dev/sdb5 and then reboot. Now I don't see the boot menu anymore so Ubuntu starts automatically. And the message keeps preventing me from starting my first session with Ubuntu. Do you have any suggestions for this? Looking forward to your reply.