# Emergency Mode due to disk corruption

Tags: fstab, disk

I am writing to save others time if they get into an issue and end up in Emergency Mode due to a corrupt entry in `/etc/fstab`.

[image]

This has already been asked, but I couldn't get the resolution quickly and had to dig a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply edited the `/etc/fstab` using

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and removed the recently added partition entry from the file. Mine was `/dev/sda2` which I removed.

Then I rebooted using `sudo systemctl reboot` and it worked.

Taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/794443/657584) to the question *“Welcome to emergency mode!” Think it is a fsck problem*.