# Reset root password for Ubuntu 16.04 - recovery mode asks for root password

Tags: password, root, recovery-mode

We've lost the root password from our file server from supermicro server.

I tried to follow the common instructions to reboot with left shift and drop to root shell as it is described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/660995).

When I choose root in this menu:

[image: menu]

Ubuntu still asks for root password or propose to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to Recovery menu.

Are there any other ways to reset root password?

Comment: You have physical access to  this machine? Boot it with a life USB is an option too.

Comment: Yes I have access. But what soul I do with usb?

Comment: in live CD after Ctrl-Alt-F1, I login as ubuntu and empty pass. then I do sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt. Then I do sudo chroot /mnt. This command did not work: "chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory. Nevertheless, chroot --help gives me a help.

Comment: seen https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128046/chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory for that. Chroot is not missing, it is missing stuff inside your chroot environment to properly start up

Comment: note: as you have selected "Drop to root shell prompt" you get an intermediate prompt, press ENTER at that prompt to get to the root shell.

Comment: Use [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/435347/527764) if you can't access recovery mode

Comment: @zlon If `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` shows no errors and then `sudo chroot /mnt` fails with the error message `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`, that means the `bash` shell was not found in the usual place inside the partition mounted in `/mnt`. Although there are several *possible* causes for that, in practice it simply means that you **mounted the wrong partition**. Your installed system's root partition is *not* always `/dev/sda1`. You've accepted an answer, indicating that this is now solved. Was that the cause? Was your root partition not `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: not a duplicate. root seems to be different than "first user"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have physical access to the machine you can do this via an Live USB/CD.

1. Boot from your USB and chose 'Try Ubuntu' instead of 'Install Ubuntu'.

   [image]
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and first look what device handle your machine disk has. You can do that with `lsblk` which should yield an output like this (I used a live CD for this since I am reproducing the steps in a VM):

   ```
   $ lsblk
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
   ├─sda1   8:2    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
   └─sda2   8:3    0 103,2G  0 part /
   sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  /cdrom
   ```

   So in this case it would be `/dev/sda2` but this could differ for your installation.
3. Now mount the partition in question with:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
   ```
4. Now coming to the part where you can finally<sup>**1**</sup> `chroot` into it.

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

   You will see that your prompt has changed to something like `root@ubuntu:/#` and now the next steps are pretty straightforward.
5. Change the password for your users with `passwd`:

   ```
   passwd root
   passwd <main-user>
   ```

   This should have done it already, but if that for whatever case setting passwords with the `passwd` command fails, you can go deep down the rabbit hole and [change the `/etc/shadow` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/165249/522934), but **Beware: this is quite dangerous and you do this at your own risk**.
6. Exit the `chroot`by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or type exit. Unmount the machine with `sudo umount /mnt` and then reboot by `sudo reboot`. You want to take the USB/CD out and make sure you're actually booting the machine in question.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> That `chroot`ing method is sufficient to reset passwords, or even to add and remove users from groups, but it does not allow you to fully use the installed system through the chroot. Many other commands, such as `apt`, would fail if you ran them in a chroot set up that way.

*If* you ever need to perform more extensive repairs on an installed system that you are accessing from a live CD/DVD/USB--for example by installing, removing, or updating software--then you would want to set up some additional mounts before `chroot`ing. You would do that by running these commands *after* running `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` but *before* running `sudo chroot /mnt`:

```
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
```

If you have multiple partitions for the different parts of the OS, like for example a separate `/boot` partition, then you would want to mount them to the right positions. For example, where `sdX` is the device name for that particular drive and `n` is the partition number:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXn /mnt/boot
```

It is fine if you run those commands before `chroot`ing in to reset passwords with the `passwd` command. It is not necessary, though.

Comment: You saved me a lot of headache:) thx