# lost my username/administrator passwords

Tags: password

I am the only user of my computer so when I installed ubuntu 17.10 I just used a one letter password now when I check settings user my password has changed to: five letters? numbers? I only see five dots
I can not install any packages with sudo and, my old password How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) and [Reset root password for Ubuntu 16.04 - recovery mode asks for root password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980102/reset-root-password-for-ubuntu-16-04-recovery-mode-asks-for-root-password)

Comment: The fact that the password field shows five stars (like `*****`) is **not** an indication that your password consists of 5 characters