# Cannot get past Emergency Mode Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 17.10

I'm working on both Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 as a dual boot system. Suddenly today I restarted PC from Windows and tried to logged into Ubuntu and then I got stuck at emergency mode. Now I can't get pass the emergency mode.
This is what I get and I'm stuck in this screen

```
[   0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errdata; please update
[   1.982327] ACPI_Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)
[   1.982338] ACPI_Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
[   3.199674] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun o
[   3.199760] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe a FIFO underrun
[   3.455294] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   3.455351] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
/dev/sda10: clean, 473657/2869776 files, 5567557/1147616 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or D to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
```

When I try to exit by pressing ctrl+D I it loads until 4.9% and redirected to this same screen. So I can't get pass trying to boot into default mode.

I checked and followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem) askubuntu question by unmounting and running `fsck -y` for root directory with Ubuntu live cd. I don't think this is windows stutdown issue as I have been using the dual boot system for quite some time.

So, how can I get pass this and work on Ubuntu ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `journalctl -xb`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually one of your file systems is faulty and needs check, 
a good practice before anything is to check all your file systems:

`sudo fsck -y /dev/sda2`

`sudo fsck -y /dev/sda3`

`...`

and so on.