# Unable to boot after formatting extra hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an extra hard drive that I wanted to repartition. My system is on a separate solid state drive. I booted off a USB drive and used disks to delete the existing partitions and repartition the drive.

When I try rebooting, Ubuntu is unable to start, and the computer enters emergency mode.

I would greatly appreciate any help trying to understand what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: What's "emergency mode"? You're positive you didn't erase your main drive, or the USB?

Comment: I actually managed to sort it out. I needed to update /etc/fstab to reflect the changes. As for what emergency mode is, I don't entirely know. I only know it's called that because it said it was.

Comment: Hmmm, searching for "ubuntu emergency mode" proved enlightening, this Q might be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem. How did you change fstab, did it use /dev/sda type labels? Identifying partitions by UUID is more robust, the a, b, c letters in sda, sdb, sdc aren't guaranteed to stay the same after reboot, and adding a new drive can change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After formatting the drive, /etc/fstab was no longer accurate. Once it was appropriately updated, everything started functioning normally again.