# Eliminating newer Kernel images

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel, 17.10

A few weeks ago, i had my Ubuntu 17.10 with kernel version 4.13.0-37. I  accidentally deleted a few important packages like `network-manager`, and i could not connect to internet at all when i booted. So i decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.4.0-21-generic from DVD keeping my `$HOME` intact. It worked. I can boot when i select the 4.4.0-21-generic option from my GRUB2 menu.

[image]

When i try to boot from the kernel 4.13.0-37, it goes into emergency mode, and i tried this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem). I still booted in emergency mode, `e2fsck` said that root filesystem is clean.

My question is how can i eliminate the newer versions of the kernel, will i ever be able to upgrade from 4.4.0-21-generic.

**Edit 1**:
I did an update&&upgrade today, and the kernel updated to 4.4.0-116, and i could boot from this kernel image, what i do not understand is, this image was already existing on my filesystem, but it booted only after it upgraded from  4.4.0-21-generic.

Answer (score 1):

I too have some strange issue with Kernel version 4.13.0-37 which came as update for Ubuntu 16.04. But removing kernel is not prescribed option.Because it also removes other important linux header packages when you run `sudo apt autoremove`.  This results in removing network-manager and many more.

I found possible solution is to edit Grub2 boot order.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2

To change boot order of kernel edit (GRUB_DEFAULT=0)

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

the first index starts from 0. So set the value as

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>9"
```

for second menu (Advanced) and 10th kernel option

I hope this will fix the problem till you received new kernel update.

Comment: I did not do what you sugeested yet, but,  i did an update&&upgrade today, and the kernel updated to 4.4.0-116, and i could boot from this kernel image, what i do not understand is, this image was already existing on my filesystem, but it booted after it upgraded from  4.4.0-21-generic.