# Problem "You are in emergency mode"

Tags: dual-boot

i have this problem with my desktop computer dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 & windows 7.
windows work well but i choice Ubuntu give me this problem.

```
You are in emergency mode.
```

this is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=ce0f60ea-7a52-4e22-9934-bf523b0a64db /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=9eaf47d2-a746-4da7-bc0d-6a7fc1bb5224 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a230235a-1495-4457-a217-5980939bc9b3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

How to fix this Problem, Please Help?

Comment: See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem

Comment: This can't fix the problem..